# putting x=sin(t)+3 in terms of t

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

For

$x = \sin(t)+3$

would it be correct to say that

$t = \arcsin(x-3) $

be correct even though this would mean that it's possible for $x$ to not be between $-1$ and $1$?

Comment: We need $$-1\le x-3\le1\iff2\le x\le4$$

Comment: $x$ has no reason to be in $[-1,1]$. Can you tell why ?

Comment: You only have $\;t\equiv \arcsin(x-3)\mod2\pi$ or  $\;t\equiv \pi-\arcsin(x-3)\mod2\pi$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust i am not sure why, or what you mean, becauase from my understanding arcsin is only considered the inverse for sin if x is in [-1,1]

Comment: @Darko: what you say is inaccurate and leads you to the error: it's the *argument* of the function which must be in this range, not $x$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust so you are saying that t has to be in [-1,1] because if it is then arcsin(x-3) will always be valid?

Comment: Not at all. What is the argument of the arc sine ?

Comment: (x-3), oh okay, i thought u were disagreeing with the other commenters, hence did not consider it an option

Comment: When there is no "@", I am talking to the OP (you).

Answer (score 0):

Unless one restricts $\sin t$ to the interval $\left[-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right]$ here are many solutions, one for each integer value of $k$

$$ t=(-1)^k\sin^{-1}(x-3)+k\pi $$

for $t$ in the interval $\left[-\dfrac{\pi}{2}+k\pi,\dfrac{\pi}{2}+k\pi\right]$.

Look [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ibqop2se69) a desmos.com demonstration